# Padding around UIImageView. Swift 3

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView`, where I don't want the image to 'touch' the edge of the view, rather have some 'padding' around it. However, I have tried the following, and for some reason it doesnt change:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pictureOutletOne: UIImageView!

//set the image
pictureOutletOne.image = UIImage(named: itemOne)

//set the padding
pictureOutletOne.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

I have also tried:

```
pictureOutletOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
pictureOutletOne.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 100, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

I have read alot about this, but these are the solutions I have found, but they aren't working. Using `Swift 3`.

Thanks so much.

Comment: `layoutMargins` only affect subviews that use them. `UIImageView` renders image inside in a non-UIView way so you should follow with the answer below where you wrap it into `UIView`

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437504/adding-padding-and-border-to-an-uiimageview

Answer (score 30):

**Swift 4.2 & 5**

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: 
"image")?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -5, left: -5, bottom: -5, 
right: -5))
```

Insets should be given in negative value

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will not work with image views with rounded borders.

Answer (score 9):

You can insert the imageView into a view and set constraints to sides, guaranteed approach :)

Comment: Dominik. Thanks. I'm a beginner, how do you place the imageView into a view?

Comment: You can select the imageView and go to menu, Editor > Embed In > View. Doing it, you imageView will be allocated into a new created view. But don't forget to reapply the constraints.

Comment: This works only if you assume the person is using a nib or storyboard. This won't help in code.

Comment: @TJOlsen you can apply the same approach in code with NSLayoutConstraint and UIView.

Answer (score 6):

Override the `alignmentRectInsets` property in a new class:

```
class PaddedImageView: UIImageView {
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little helper extension I build:

```
extension UIImage {
    func addPadding(_ padding: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let alignmentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -padding, left: -padding,
                                          bottom: -padding, right: -padding)
        return withAlignmentRectInsets(alignmentInset)
    }
}
```

Use Case:

```
let image = UIImage("Image Name")
image.addPadding(10)
```

Comment: @CristianCapannini please be kind. I have added a use case, so you have an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
let padding: CGFloat = 10    
myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png").resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding), resizingMode: .stretch)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Swift 5*

Adds padding to right and left of an image place in an image view.

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill")
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -15, bottom: 0, right: -15)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image.withAlignmentRectInsets(insets))
```

> Note: UIStackView honors alignment insets as contributors to an image view's intrinsic content size.
>
>
>
> Use case example:
>
> In my application, I have a vertical stack comprised of a small center-aligned `UILabel` stacked above a `UIImageView` in a `UITableViewCell`. Label width varies from cell to cell, varying respective vertical stack widths and shifting images' respective horizontal alignments. I.e. the images don't line up in the table.... By padding images with horizontal alignment insets, it forces vertical stack to have a consistent width greater than max expected label width, keeping images center-aligned vertically in the table.