# Adding padding and border to an UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

How can I add padding between an `UIImageView` and its border?

```
Img.layer.cornerRadius = Img.bounds.width / 2
Img.layer.borderWidth = 2
Img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
Img.clipsToBounds = true
```

Like this:

[image: desired result]

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021478/add-transparent-space-around-a-uiimage

Answer (score 26):

As per the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021478/add-transparent-space-around-a-uiimage)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let image = UIImage(named: "imagename")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image.imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 30, 30, 30)))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 400)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
extension UIImage {
    func imageWithInsets(insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
            CGSize(width: self.size.width + insets.left + insets.right,
                   height: self.size.height + insets.top + insets.bottom), false, self.scale)
        let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let origin = CGPoint(x: insets.left, y: insets.top)
        self.draw(at: origin)
        let imageWithInsets = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageWithInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "view" in view.addSubview(imageView) supposed to be? It's throwing me an error. Do I need to add a UIView to the image?

Comment: Its just the view in ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

For adding padding to the UIImage of UIImageView, use the below piece of code in Swift

```
let padding: CGFloat = 6    
myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png").resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding), resizingMode: .stretch)
```