# Add padding around circular image view in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, imageview

I've seen many variations of posts about adding padding to an image but none that have been able to help me. If you cannot provide me with an answer, can any of you all please steer me in the correct direction?

I have a circular imageview. I would like to add space around the circular image view before the border is shown such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDC4Y.png)

How can i implement this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437504/swift-3-adding-padding-and-border-to-an-imageview/46437819#46437819

Comment: @ViniApp This did not help at all. All it did was add a view over my entire image

Answer (score 2):

To do this, I embedded my UIImageView in a UIView. I set the constraints so that the the UIImageview is always a certain distance inside the the UIView. Then I gave the UIView the following properties:

```
    view.backgroundColor = nil
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.width / 2
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```